# Where can I find Cardano's academic research papers?

Tags: reference-request

Where can I find the academic research papers related to Cardano?  I tried Google Scholar with no success.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What search terms did you use on Google Scholar?

Answer (score 18):

IOHK has a list of papers and currently I see 103 of them:
https://iohk.io/en/research/library/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to https://iohk.io/en/research/library/ (as Joshua Chia mentions), you can then utilize [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com) to search for a paper's title and/or author names to also get a list of citing articles. I'm surprised you didn't have success with the site. Of course, you can also just search for *cardano blockchain* to get papers that are not necessarily written by IOG staff.

If [Scite.ai](https://scite.ai/) would implement a better search and index more databases, I'd recommend them over Google Scholar due to the fact that there's also a sentiment analysis (supporting/contrasting in addition to Goggle's only type: mentioning cites) on citations.

Getting an idea on how other academics approach the paper you are interested in can aid in pre-digesting the Cardano-related papers.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta go to crypto and or other tertiary domain specific archives. https://eprint.iacr.org/complete/ is one that I use myself quite frequently. Just look up IOG scientists if you're looking for Cardano specific papers.